# jeditable submit on mouse out

Tags: jquery, jeditable

having a bit of trouble with jeditable plugin for jquery and was hoping someone wiser than myself can help.

Essentially I am trying to trigger the editable function on mouseover and submit any changes on mouse leave... sounds simple but the mouse leave bit doesnt seem very well documented :( This is kinda what I have so far:

```
$('.content').live("mouseenter", function() {
    console.log("enter");

    $('.editable', $(this)).editable(function(value, settings) {
        //do stuff
    });

}).live("mouseleave", function() {
    console.log("leave");

    $('.editable', $(this)).editable(function(value, settings) {
        //stop doing stuff
    });
})
```

So anyone have any idea how I submit the editable content and reset the content when mousing out? It only seems to work with a click :(

Answer (score 1):

There is an `onblur` option, which allows you to specify the behaviour when the element being edited is *blurred*. To achieve what you are after, you could specify `onblur: 'submit'`, and on `mouseleave`, you can make the element blur, e.g. `$('.editable', this).blur()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use mouseover and mouseout as suggested in the jQuery documentation like so:

```
$(".hoverme").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks much tidier than my code, but its more the trigger event that im stuck on with the jeditable. I dont know how to trigger the submitting of then jeditable content on mouse out?

Comment: oh, you want to know how to submit a web form with javascript?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit/133997#133997